# FBA Users - SMTP Settings

Tags: forms-authentication

We used FBA instead of Active Direct Integration. SharePoint is configured for SMTP. we have checked that this works. we receive alerts from within SharePoint if you sign up to them. However in the FBA users module where you can reset a users password by sending them a temp one to their email address this just doesn't work. Help!

Answer (score 0):

Do the FBA Users you added have external email addresses outside of your domain (gmail.com, hotmail.com, microsoft.com....)?  If that's the case, try setting up a user with an internal email address and see if it works.  If the internal email address works, you need to allow 'Relaying' to the SMTP server from your SharePoint server.

There's some info here on allowing relaying with the Microsoft SMTP server:
http://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/install-and-configure-php-on-iis/configure-smtp-e-mail-in-iis-7-and-above

Comment: hi thanks for replying. if I sign up to alerts within SP I receive emails from SP no problem. they are also very quick to come through. if I go to the FBA user admin section and ask it to send a new password to my email address, the exact same as the alerts they never come through. we are proper stumped. sharepoint has office 365 email account, with the exact same domain name for my email address

Comment: When you say the FBA user admin section, do you mean the user management page for the FBA Pack? If so, it uses SharePoint's email capability, same as the alerts, so it should work. Maybe try creating some new FBA accounts with other internal email addresses and see if they go through.  Also, check the SharePoint log file - failed email sends should be logged there along with some more details of why it failed.

Comment: its the FBA User Management within SharePoint. im not sure how to get to the FBA pack

Comment: That's probably the FBA Pack (SharePoint doesn't have an 'FBA User Management' screen, adding the FBA Pack adds it).